# kernel centering around mean when samples belong to positive or negative class

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

suppose I have a kernel matrix of 6x6 .Also i have label information indicating that 1 to 3 samples belong to label(i.e positive label) and 4 to 6 samples do not belong to label(negative label). **I want to center the 1-3 samples around the mean of positive label and 4-6 samples around the mean of the negative label.**
 How to do that?
Also how to calculate the **mean for negative and positive labels?**
I know that mean of a kernel matrix is calculated by summation of all the kernel matrix elements and dividing by the total number of elements.
In the same way **can I add all the entries of positive label and divide by number of positive elements** , i.e here in this example for positive mean, add all elements of first three rows and divide by 3x6=18. 
Can it be done in this way ? why or why not please explain.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: sir i have edited the post . i just want to know to to center data when there are two classes